# How should I specify the query conditions in INNER JOIN queries like these?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM TableOne
INNER JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.ForeignKeyID = TableTwo.PrimaryKeyID
WHERE TableTwo.SomeColumnOne = 12345;
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM TableOne
INNER JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.ForeignKeyID = TableTwo.PrimaryKeyID
AND TableTwo.SomeColumnOne = 12345;
```

I prefer the first method since `JOIN` tell us how the two tables should be bound together whereas `WHERE` tell us how to filter the result set. But is there any performance difference between the two ? Or any other reason why we should prefer one over the other ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: @zxc: the difference in the queries is the first one uses a WHERE clause, whilst the second one adds the extra condition into the ON clause with an AND. I don't know about MySQL in particular, but would expect most databases to treat them the same for INNER JOINS in terms of functionality and performance.

Comment: @Sadikhasan It is not a duplicate. The question that you have shared is about whether or not we should use `INNER JOIN`. But the question that I'm asking is how the query conditions (which are not acting on PK Columns) should be specified when THERE IS an `INNER JOIN` between the tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableOne
INNER JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.ForeignKeyID = TableTwo.PrimaryKeyID
WHERE TableTwo.SomeColumnOne = 12345;
```

here the `WHERE` clause is applicable on the result of `INNER JOIN`

whereas

```
SELECT *
FROM TableOne
INNER JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.ForeignKeyID = TableTwo.PrimaryKeyID
AND TableTwo.SomeColumnOne = 12345;
```

in second case the `INNER JOIN` will be performed with filtered result of `TableTwo` after the `AND` condition.

Comment: While theoretically correct, any decent optimizer will convert these queries to be the same.

Comment: @Archana So if we assume that the query optimizer will not convert the queries to the same one, it is better to use the second query since this leads to a `JOIN` on smaller result, right ?

Comment: @Archana: can you show any evidence of the second version being better, as I concur with the earlier comment that most/all databases will execute these in exactly the same way, unless their optimiser was written from scratch over a weekend.

Comment: @mc110 I think she meant that second will be better if we assume that the optimizer doesn't convert them to the same query.